DataDog sum of binary metrics
I have a collection of binary metrics that provide a value every 10s or so. I want to track the number of these that are one at a given point in time, then take a max of this.
I can almost get what I want with .rollup(sum, 10).max() in a graph, however over longer time spans, the limit on the number of time slices overrides the 10s stipulated in .rollup(), so the sum is taken over a longer time interval and multiple values from each metric are added.
If I could create a new metric that contans the value of the .rollup(sum,10) operation, this would fulfil my requirement.
